# Is it "close votes" or "close votes"?

Tags: support

In the review queue "Close Votes" is the word "close" meaning [close1 or close4](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/close)?

IE

"klohzz" `: to bring together the parts or edges of (something open)`

or

"klohss" `: near in space : not far away or distant`

?

In the explanation for the queue it says `Vote whether or not to close questions with close votes`. The first usage of "close" is obviously close1, but the second one is ambiguous. Are these questions with contention, or just questions we are seeking to shut?

Comment: The former. The question is open, until it's closed.

Comment: Until this morning I though it was questions that had otherwise been contentious between "it's fine" and "close it". Egg on my face. :@(

Comment: I think you're overthinking this definition.

Comment: it's obviously 1. why would we mark questions as physically close together?

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC because if something has had like 5 upvotes and 4 downvotes there is something weird going-on with it and could use more eyeballs. Maybe good content very poorly written. Maybe good content but questionable site fit. If it provokes strong reaction in both directions, it could use more eyeballs and generate discussion.

Answer (score 7):

Same as closing a door. The door stays open until someone is using physical power to push it closed (close vote), or higher forces (e.g. wind) use a binding vote to do that.

Answer (score -1):

The English language is full of words that share the same spelling but sound different. They are referred to as [Homographs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homograph).

The key in interpreting a homograph is to examine the context. In this case, it appears you have misinterpreted the context to be something other than what it is, which is "close" in the sense of being the opposite of "open," not the opposite of "far," which would make absolutely no sense whatsoever.

Comment: a "close vote" makes sense when there are two directions or options. The term "close election", "close race", and "close vote". Here is a [recent usage](http://www.canada.com/health/10392050/story.html). Reviewing posts that have lots of upvotes and lots of vote in nearly equal measure is perfectly coherent and not unreasonable in this context. In this usage of "close" the "near in space" is metaphorical.

Comment: Yes, it is an unreasonable extension of logic. A "close" election is close because the vote tallies for either candidate add up to the same number within a margin of error. That is not at all applicable for "votes to close" as there is only one option. Either you vote, or don't vote.  Voting to close has nothing to do with the number of up or down votes on the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are begging the question.`Voting to close has nothing to do with the number of up or down votes on the question.` implies that you already understand that "close" refers to "closing". "Close Votes" could just as easily be a queue for reviewing questions that have gotten an equal (or "close") number of upvotes and downvotes. Those kind of questions with close4 votes could be good candidates for a close1 vote. That would be a terrible sentence, but it is still possible and actually what I understood at first.

Comment: I disagree. I suspect there are not many questions with equal number of up and down votes (if you exclude 1 up/ 1 dn) and if there are, I don't see that as being an indicator the question should be closed (I'm sure the data is available). But voting is not the same as flagging - you can down-vote an answer because it was poorly-written. You can down-vote a question because it did not show much research effort, which in both cases are not valid reasons to delete or close.